# Include json in this d3.js calendar view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, d3.js

I'm new to d3 charts and javascript, and this has been an uphill battle.

After a bunch a research, I was able to populate the chart with a CSV file. So now, I'm trying to populate the chart with `json` data.

This is my code. It's loosely based on [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/benlyall/b237f16dda3125423130). But I prefer using my code (ie. d3.v4):

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 136,
  cellSize = 17;

var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([9000, 12000])
  .range(["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Black"]);
var dateParse = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(d3.range(2017, 2018))
  .enter().append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + cellSize * 3.5 + ")rotate(-90)")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var rect = svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.timeDays(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", cellSize)
  .attr("height", cellSize)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(d), d) * cellSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.getDay() * cellSize;
  })
  .datum(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#000")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.timeMonths(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
  })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", pathMonth);

d3.json("data3.json", function(error, data) {
  //populating data since i don't have the file
  data = [{
    "date": "2017-01-04",
    "open": 10430.69
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-05",
    "open": 10584.56
  }];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = dateParse(new Date(d.date));
    console.log(d.dd);
  });

  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.dd;
    })
    .map(data);

  rect.filter(function(d) {
      return d in data;
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(data[d]);
    })
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d + ": " + data[d];
    });
});

function pathMonth(t0) {
  var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
    d0 = t0.getDay(),
    w0 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t0), t0),
    d1 = t1.getDay(),
    w1 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t1), t1);
  return "M" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "," + d0 * cellSize +
    "H" + w0 * cellSize + "V" + 7 * cellSize +
    "H" + w1 * cellSize + "V" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize +
    "H" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + 0 +
    "H" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "Z";
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few changes needed for your code to work. These are mostly related to the use of `data` instead of `nest`, and a minor change (for which I cannot find information on) in d3 v4 as compared with d3 v3.

**Filter**

Firstly, you are not filtering your data correctly:

You do not want to filter like this:

```
return d in data;
```

The `in` operator is for properties of an object, `data` is an array.
You want to filter by your nest (as in the example):

```
return d in nest;
```

Secondly, at least in my brief testing, d3.nest behaves slightly differently in d3 v4 (this might be dependent on version, I've used 4.9.1 (min) in the snippet below). When using keys that begin with numbers, d3 seems to be appending a dollar sign at the beginning of each key when using d3.nest:

D3v4 example:

```js
data = [{
    "date": "2017-01-04", "open": 10430.69
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-05", "open": 10584.56
  }];

  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .map(data);
 
 console.log(nest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Compared with D3v3:

```js
data = [{
    "date": "2017-01-04", "open": 10430.69
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-05", "open": 10584.56
  }];

  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .map(data);
 
 console.log(nest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If you are seeing this behaviour, you'll need to change your filter accordingly:

```
return ("$" + d) in nest;
```

**Accessing Nest Properties**

Thirdly, as `data` is just an array, `data[d]` is not likely to get desired results as `d` will  be a date string, you need to access the `nest` object. Logging `nest` might help in finding the proper properties. Instead of:

```
return color(data[d]);
```

Try:

```
return color(nest[("$" + d)][0].open);
```

Which is very similar to the linked example in the question (with the exception of that dollar sign thing again).

---

**Optimization**

Related to your other recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026524/not-understanding-result-of-d3-timeparsehttp://), this code

```js
    var date = "2017-01-02";
    var dateParse = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
    console.log(dateParse(new Date(date)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

does nothing. It takes a string representing a date and converts it to a date object, then converts it back into the same string representation you started with. You can drop this portion of the code, it was used in the linked example because it was converting from a m/d/Y date string to a date object, and then to a Y-m-d date string. Your initial date format is already in the format you want, so there is no need to modify it. Use just:

```
  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.date;
    })
    .map(data);
```

Rather than:

```
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = dateParse(d.date);
  });

  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.dd;
    })
    .map(data);
```

---

**Result**

These changes (I've stripped out the text to make the example simpler, removed the external file reference, etc) result in:

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 136,
  cellSize = 17;

var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([9000, 12000])
  .range(["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Black"]);
  
var dateFormat = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(d3.range(2017, 2018))
  .enter().append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");

var rect = svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.timeDays(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", cellSize)
  .attr("height", cellSize)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(d), d) * cellSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.getDay() * cellSize;
  })
  .datum(dateFormat);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#000")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.timeMonths(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
  })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", pathMonth);

  data = [{
    "date": "2017-01-04",
    "open": 10430.69
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-05",
    "open": 10584.56
  }];

  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.date;
    })
    .map(data);

 rect.filter(function(d) {
      return ("$" + d) in nest;
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { 
      return color(nest[("$" + d)][0].open);
    })


function pathMonth(t0) {
  var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
    d0 = t0.getDay(),
    w0 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t0), t0),
    d1 = t1.getDay(),
    w1 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t1), t1);
  return "M" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "," + d0 * cellSize +
    "H" + w0 * cellSize + "V" + 7 * cellSize +
    "H" + w1 * cellSize + "V" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize +
    "H" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + 0 +
    "H" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "Z";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One last question: if the data in the example instead came from a file called `data.json`, how would I integrate this into the code?

Comment: Same as you had it originally, with `d3.json("file.json",...` but without the `var data = ...`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had tried that but I was missing the `});` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were forgetting to declare dateParse (and using it wrong).

`var dateParse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");`

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 136,
  cellSize = 17;

var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([9000, 12000])
  .range(["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Black"]);
var dateParse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(d3.range(2017, 2018))
  .enter().append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + cellSize * 3.5 + ")rotate(-90)")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var rect = svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.timeDays(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", cellSize)
  .attr("height", cellSize)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(d), d) * cellSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.getDay() * cellSize;
  })
  .datum(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#000")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d3.timeMonths(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1));
  })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", pathMonth);

d3.json("data3.json", function(error, data) {
  //populating data since i don't have the file
  data = [{
    "date": "2017-01-04",
    "open": 10430.69
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-05",
    "open": 10584.56
  }];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = dateParse(d.date);
    console.log(d.dd);
  });

  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.dd;
    })
    .map(data);

  rect.filter(function(d) {
      return d in data;
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(data[d]);
    })
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d + ": " + data[d];
    });
});

function pathMonth(t0) {
  var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
    d0 = t0.getDay(),
    w0 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t0), t0),
    d1 = t1.getDay(),
    w1 = d3.timeWeek.count(d3.timeYear(t1), t1);
  return "M" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "," + d0 * cellSize +
    "H" + w0 * cellSize + "V" + 7 * cellSize +
    "H" + w1 * cellSize + "V" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize +
    "H" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + 0 +
    "H" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "Z";
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, the I'm not getting any more javascript issues.

Comment: I've made some changes to the code using your example, but the chart is still not being filled. Would you be able to see if there's anything wrong with the code?

Comment: The date is in the correct format. I'm not sure why it doesn't fill the chart. Any help with this is appreciated.