# Not understanding result of d3.timeParse?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble understanding how `d3.timeParse` works. I initialize the function at the beginning like this:

```
var dateParse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
```

I then call it here:

```
d3.json("data3.json", function(error, data) {
  //populating data since i don't have the file
  data = [{
    "date": "2017-01-04",
    "open": 10430.69
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-05",
    "open": 10584.56
  }];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = dateParse(d.date);
    console.log(d.dd);
  });
```

The problem is that `console.log(d.dd);` returns the following string

> Wed Jan 04 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)

when it should return this:

> 2017-01-04

I've tried changing the format of the parameter (if that's what this really is) from `"%Y-%m-%d"` to anything else, but any change returns *null*.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... The code parses the string to a date object and logs the string representation of that very object. As far as I can see it does exactly what it is supposed to. Why would you parse a date string and have it printed out unchanged? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `timeFormat`, and wrap `d.date` to `new Date(d.date)`:

```js
  var dateParse = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
  var data = [{
    "date": "2017-01-04",
    "open": 10430.69
  }, {
    "date": "2017-01-05",
    "open": 10584.56
  }];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = dateParse(new Date(d.date));
    console.log(d.dd);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would you be possible to look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011739/include-json-in-this-d3-js-calendar-view)? It's the reason I'm doing all of this and I still can't figure out why the chart isn't filling up.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea about solution of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use moment.js library and all your date-related operations can become very easy. https://momentjs.com/

If you have the library you can try this

```js
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = moment(d["date"], "YYYY-MM-DD");;
    console.log(d.dd);
  });
```