# Nest() function in D3 v4 generating keys with $ sign

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am using the d3.nest() function for the first time in an attempt to draw a choropleth in d3. Now when I nest the years and country, I see that a "$" sign is appended to both country (like $AUS) and year (like $1960). So, is it expected that I need to access the  array as dataByCountryAndyear['$AUS'] ?

I read this post:

[Include json in this d3.js calendar view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011739/include-json-in-this-d3-js-calendar-view)

It seems that the behavior is expected in d3 v4, however I want to understand what is the right way to access the object using a key in this scenario.

```
function ready(error, country_data, lfpr_data) {

  // converting strings to numbers where necessary
  lfpr_data.forEach(d => {
        d.year = +d.year
        d.female_lfpr = +d.female_lfpr;
        d.male_lfpr = +d.male_lfpr;
  });

  // nesting by country and year i.e for each country all years beneath it
  var dataByCountryByYear = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.country; })
      .key(function(d) { return d.year; })
      .map(lfpr_data); 

  console.log(dataByCountryByYear['$AUS'])

  country_data.features.forEach(each_country => { 
    each_country.properties.years = dataByCountryByYear[each_country.id]
  });
}
```

My data looks like below:

```
year    country country_name    region  female_lfpr male_lfpr   total_lfpr
1960    ABW Aruba   Latin America & Caribbean   NA  NA  NA
1960    AFG Afghanistan South Asia  NA  NA  NA
1960    AGO Angola  Sub-Saharan Africa  NA  NA  NA
1960    ALB Albania Europe & Central Asia   NA  NA  NA
1960    AND Andorra Europe & Central Asia   NA  NA  NA
1960    ARE United Arab Emirates    Middle East & North Africa  NA  NA  NA
1960    ARG Argentina   Latin America & Caribbean   NA  NA  NA
1960    ARM Armenia Europe & Central Asia   NA  NA  NA
1960    ASM American Samoa  East Asia & Pacific NA  NA  NA
1960    ATG Antigua and Barbuda Latin America & Caribbean   NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using [`entries`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/v1.0.7/README.md#nest_entries), which...

> Applies the nest operator to the specified array, returning an **array** of key-values entries. (emphasis mine)

Instead, you're using [`map`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/v1.0.7/README.md#nest_map), which:

> Applies the nest operator to the specified array, returning a nested **map**. (emphasis mine)

So, what your getting as the result of the `nest` is not an array, but a [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). It's a different kind of object.

That being said, your two questions:

1. `d3.map` will automatically set the keys starting with a `$` sign, as you can see in D3 [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/5aad1d67f264c0b3b6a9f3e9833021497f03beeb/src/map.js#L1):

   ```
   export var prefix = "$";
   ```

   But you don't need to mind about that prefix (more about that below).
2. Since that's a map, not an array, you have to use map's methods, like `has`, `get` or `set`. And when using those methods you **don't need** to use the dollar sign.

Here is an example with your code/data:

```js
const csv = `year,country,country_name,region,female_lfpr male_lfpr,total_lfpr
1960,ABW,Aruba,Latin America & Caribbean,NA,NA,NA
1960,AFG,Afghanistan,South Asia,NA,NA,NA`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv);

const dataByCountryByYear = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.country;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.year;
  })
  .map(data);

console.log(dataByCountryByYear.has("AFG"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```